# How to handle https page to open in webBrowser control even if its an unsecure connection in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

Currently, when I am opening a https url on WebBrowser control, its displaying an error page which states  An untrusted site either to proceed or not. So once i click on proceed it will open the url.

How to avoid this untrusted dialog and directly opens the https page without any user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

Must be an issue with your device's date and time settings.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create your own browser to break this rule.

Probably will have others problems doing this.

Better check your TLS or use only http